# Passportjs google authentication in nodejs running on serverless lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, google-oauth, passport.js, serverless

In a normal node rest API it will be easy for us to call the passport in the routes itself. Since I'm using serverless lambda for rest API, it doesn't have any routers. Instead from serverless.yml file I can call the handlers alone and calling passport.authenticate from that place is not returning any response properly. How to use passportjs in nodejs with serverless lambda?

I have tried both callback and return promise method.

**serverless.yml**

```
google:
  handler: handlers/user.google
  events:
    - http:
        path: /auth/google
        method: get
        cors: true
googlecallback:
  handler: handlers/user.googlecallback
  events:
    - http:
        path: /auth/google/callback
        method: get
        cors: true
```

**handlers/user.js**

```
cost passport = require("passport"),
GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth").OAuth2Strategy;

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: config.google.clientId,
      clientSecret: config.google.clientSecrect,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/dev/auth/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      return done(err, profile);
    }
  )
);

module.exports.google = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  return callback(null,passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"],
  }));
}
module.exports.googlecallback = async (event, context) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve(passport.authenticate("google", { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: "/login" }))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code executing in the lambda can't access the public internet. Try the same by associating the lambda with VPC that have access to internet.
Refer the comment of "Superlokkus" on page -  https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/651